# Packages built via Poetry can't be imported after installation

Tags: python, flask, pip

I'm trying to build a Flask application managed via Poetry. The application contains a `src` folder with an `api` folder for the Flask app and a `lib` folder for a shared library for notebooks and other scripts.

I want to be able to run `poetry build` and install flask via `pip install dist/**.whl` command in order to run it via gunicorn.

However when I run `pip install *.whl` I can see that package `mypackage` is listed in `pip freeze`, but I can't import it in python shell, instead I get `ModuleNotFoundError`

```py
import myproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'
```

Here the structure:

```
- pyproject.toml
- src
-- lib
-- api
---- __init__.py
```

`pyproject.toml` contains the following settings:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypackage"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{ include = "api", from = "src" }]
exclude = ['notebooks']

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
openai = "^0.27.5"
pymongo = "^4.3.3"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.0"
boto3 = "^1.26.123"
pandas = "^2.0.1"
datasets = "^2.12.0"
pysbd = "^0.3.4"
transformers = "^4.28.1"
nltk = "^3.8.1"
torch = "^2.0.0"
flask = "^2.3.1"
s3fs = "0.4.2"
faiss-cpu = "^1.7.4"
gunicorn = "^20.1.0"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
autopep8 = "^2.0.2"
pylint = "^2.17.3"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Comment: You don't have a `myproject` dir inside `src`, all you have is `api`, with the current setup you have made `api` a top level package, rather than `myproject`.  Ensure that you `include = "myproject"` instead.  Do verify the contents of the generated `dist/mypackage-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` using tools such as `unzip -t`.